# Possible to repopulate locale defaults?

Tags: matrix, localization

When a locale is first created, it seems it receives all of the default locales content. Is it possible to have this happen for a specific field after the fact? I have a large matrix (with subtle locale differences) I'm hoping to not re-enter a second time ;)